# authentication : problem with symfony, no error but no authentication

Tags: php, symfony

i need help for the authentication in my application. I have create form and function with symfony doc and configurate the security.yaml but, when i give the credentials and after the redirection, i'm not authenticated. I don't found a similar problem on the net.

- loginController

```
     /**
     * Display login form and process login form (GET + POST)
     * 
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function index(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
         // get the login error if there is one
         $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

         // last username entered by the user
         $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

       return $this->render('login/index.html.twig', [
             'controller_name' => 'LoginController',
             'last_username' => $lastUsername,
             'error'         => $error,
        ]);
    }
```

-user.php

```
    public function getUserIdentifier(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Role;
    }

    public function getRoles(){

    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
```

-security.yaml

```
    providers:
        users:
            entity:
                # the class of the entity that represents users
                class: 'App\Entity\User'
                # the property to query by - e.g. email, username, etc
                property: 'Email'
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: users

            form_login:
                # "app_login" is the name of the route created previously
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
            
    access_control:
         - { path: ^/, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

-index.html.twig

```
{% block body %}
    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('app_login') }}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}"/>

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password"/>

        {# If you want to control the URL the user is redirected to on success
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account"/> #}

        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

- UsernamePasswordToken.php

```
        parent::__construct([$roles]);

        if ('' === $firewallName) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('$firewallName must not be empty.');
        }

        $this->setUser($user);
        $this->credentials = $credentials ?? null;
        $this->firewallName = $firewallName;

        parent::setAuthenticated(\count([$roles]) > 0, false);
    }
```

Comment: i've modify like you propose but it the same problem, no error and no authentication :(

Comment: i make this now, thank's

Answer (score 0):

Your, getRoles() function is returning nothing. Try to do something like :

```
 /**
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getRoles(): array
{
    $roles = $this->roles;
    // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
    $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

    return array_unique($roles);
}
```

And your getUserIdentifier is returning '$this->Role' ?
Try to return something unique like username or email :

```
/**
 * A visual identifier that represents this user.
 *
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getUserIdentifier(): string
{
    return (string) $this->username;
}
```

And also check to be sure that on LoginFormAuthenticator.php  that you are finding your user in your database by the username like fallowing :

```
  $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['username'=>$userIdentifier]);
```